# Downloading and displaying images efficiently in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, ios, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms

With devices having different resolutions and pixel densities, what's the best approach for downloading images and displaying them efficiently across those devices? Should I send a web service the size wanted for the image and have that service return the appropriately sized image?

I am not sure I'm taking the right path and I haven't found a guide about this, so, please advise. Thanks.

Comment: I just found this possible exit: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42635/what-is-they-best-way-to-load-very-large-images-on-all-3-plaforms, aligned with what I thought. Will wait for more input.

Comment: I think it is better to resize on the server, it has more power to do such operations.